# MSTest workflow activity execution error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, mstest, tfsbuild

I am getting the next output log error when executing MSTest workflow activity for my Team Build 2010:

```
MSTest
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /testcontainer:"D:\TFS\Builds\MyProyect\Debug\W_DEBUG\W_DEBUG_20111214.15\Binary\OrderedTest1.orderedtest" /publish:"http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection" /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/2550" /teamproject:"MyProyect" /platform:"Mixed Platforms" /flavor:"Debug" 
 The directory name is invalid
```

If I execute that command on my build server locally (surrounded with double quotes the MSTest.exe path) it works perfectly.

How can I set that absolute path to the MSTest activity? I have tried setting MSTest ToolPath property to:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\")
```

unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have Visual Studio installed in the build server? Without it, MsTest isn't there.

Comment: As I said, if I run that command locally (in the build server) it works perfectly. In fact, I've moved the whole folder containing the "MSTest.exe" to other path without spaces (e.g C:\Common7\IDE\...) and error persists. It is not a path-spaces thing, I have no idea of why it could be.

Comment: does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by using the following command in my build definition:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\MSTest.exe&quot; /testcontainer:
```

in this way using the variable:

```
%VS100COMNTOOLS%
```

( or `%VS90COMNTOOLS%` for Visual Studio 2008 ) I did not need to add anything to the PATH environment variable of the build server and `mstest.exe` was resolved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was the process running this was running as `SYSTEM` however when MSTest runs it appeared to be running as `MACHINENAME$` changing the owner to be a local user fixed the issue and stopped MSTest from bailing out.